# gorm postgres 15, How to work with schema?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

My environment: Windows 11 x64, go v1.20.1, gorm. I mimics at https://gorm.io/docs/#Quick-Start . I have file `a_day_learn.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    ID    uint `gorm:"primaryKey;default:auto_random()"`
    Code  string
    Price uint
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=172.16.4.184 user=postgres password=itsasecret dbname=vy port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    fmt.Println(db, err)

    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})

    insertProduct := &Product{Code: "D42", Price: 100}

    db.Create(insertProduct)
    fmt.Printf("insert ID: %d, Code: %s, Prict: %d\n",
        insertProduct.ID, insertProduct.Code, insertProduct.Price)

    readProduct := &Product{}
    db.First(&readProduct, "code = ?", "D42") // find product with code D42

    fmt.Printf("read ID: %d, Code: %s, Prict: %d\n",
        readProduct.ID, readProduct.Code, readProduct.Price)
}
```

[image]

[image]

log

```golang
GOROOT=D:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=D:\vygopath;C:\Users\admin\go #gosetup
"D:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" build -o C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___1go_build_a_day_learn_go.exe C:\Users\admin\GolandProjects\awesomeProject1\a_day_learn.go #gosetup
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___1go_build_a_day_learn_go.exe
&{0xc0000f2510 <nil> 0 0xc0001b2000 1} <nil>

2023/02/23 16:22:50 C:/Users/admin/GolandProjects/awesomeProject1/a_day_learn.go:25 ERROR: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "products" (SQLSTATE 42601)
[1.592ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "products" ("id" bigserial DEFAULT auto_random(),"code" text,"price" bigint,PRIMARY KEY ("id"))

2023/02/23 16:22:50 C:/Users/admin/GolandProjects/awesomeProject1/a_day_learn.go:29 ERROR: relation "products" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[3.108ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "products" ("code","price") VALUES ('D42',100) RETURNING "id"
insert ID: 0, Code: D42, Prict: 100

2023/02/23 16:22:50 C:/Users/admin/GolandProjects/awesomeProject1/a_day_learn.go:34 ERROR: relation "products" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[1.051ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE code = 'D42' ORDER BY "products"."id" LIMIT 1
read ID: 0, Code: , Prict: 0

Process finished with the exit code 0
```

The program cannot migration schema to real database, because missing schema. I don't know how to declare/working with schema `public` of database name `vy`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres usually needs the schema prefixed on its queries. As such, if you need to run a query over, you'll ned to set up a prefix to your connection config.

Over this row: `db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})`, you might want to set up over the Config your TablePrefix, as it follows:

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            TablePrefix:   "public.",
        },
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `default:auto_random()` , the correct one is

```golang
type Product struct {
    ID    uint `gorm:"primaryKey; column:id"`
    Code  string
    Price uint
}
```

Note that `auto_random()` support [TiDB](https://www.google.com/). only

[image]